# App upload process error - ERROR ITMS-90046: “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements.”

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-app

I am facing problem in uploading my project on iTunes after updating my XCode to XCode8. I have tried various methods to solve this like clean the project and provisioning profiles and like that but nothing worked for me. I have changed my bundle id in my first upload of a project. At that time project was upload successfully but now after xcode update, it's not woking for me. Please help me as soon as possible. 
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Application for the upload, i found an easy solution.

Instead of using the application loader to upload the application, I used the Organizer from XCode and it worked without any warnings when doing the upload!